# Accessing Pyramid DB Session within third-party library

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am writing a library for Pyramid. One aspect involves the library being provided with a model class, then retrieving all instances of the model from the database. However, I am unable to interact with the DB without access to the session factory.

In Django this was taken care of behind the scenes. With Pyramid & SQLAlchemy this is not the case.

Is there a standard way for me to get hold of the current thread's DB Session within Pyramid, and without having any knowledge of how a particular project is setup (as this is a reusable library)?

PS. I'm still getting my head around this area of SQLAlchemy, so please excuse any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify sqla session as attribute in inherited classes, like factory-boy does:
https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html?highlight=sqlalchemy#sqlalchemy

Another way is create interface and require to register sqlalchemy session in application registry as utility, before "config.include" your extension. Maybe [pyramid_jinja2](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/master/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py#L167) will clarify this solution.

Comment: Thanks @kubus, I went with the latter in the end, it seemed like the best route to take.

Comment: Configurator.add_request_method has been available since Pyramid 1.4 and is a shortcut for this use case - http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_request_method

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading about

a convention to add session to the request object. Your library makes just an assumption about that and write that in your package docs.

- http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/07/building-pyramid-applications/

Global vs. Non-Global session

- http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/database/sqlalchemy.html

A offical tutorial showing those concepts

- http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tutorial/databases.html

A lot of pyramid applications use the package zope.sqlalchemy to integrate application transaction management and DB session management. This approach is even recommended as one of many options [by SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions). Docs of zope.sqlalchemy are a bit confusing at least to me. The topic as a whole is a constant source of confusion to people starting with pyramid and thread-local sessions using SQLAlchemy.

To see a full-featured pyramid app that makes use of these packages look at [ToDoPyramid - one of the sample application listed on pyramid docs pages](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid)

I [cloned the project](https://github.com/saschagottfried/todopyramid) to make the database-related code at least more testable and readable to me. I found the concepts work very well - if the environment targetting the database is setup up properly.